# jquery.ajax - check file on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload, submit

I need to check a file on submit-event, so i did the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
        data = new FormData();
        data.append('picture', $('#picture-field')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkit.php',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.error)
            }
        });
  });
});
```

But this doesn´t work. the returned data is not diplayed, anybody could help me?

Comment: Add an `alert` to see if the `event is triggered`. Add an `error method` to see if the `url` is right. Not sure if you need to set `contentType: false`. Also, is your `JSON` valid?

Comment: looks the the form submit is not prevented which might be refreshing the page, return false from the method

Comment: ok, and how to check if file-input is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try preventing the form submit action

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        //stop the default form submit action
        e.preventDefault();

        var files = $('#picture-field')[0].files;
        if (!files.length) {
            alert('select a file')
            return;
        }

        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('picture', $('#picture-field')[0].files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkit.php',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.error)
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, status, error) {
                alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
            }
        });
    });
});
```